# In the Swift programming language, what does "slider:UISlider" mean?

Tags: swift

```
@IBAction func sliderMoved(slider:UISlider){
    currentValue = lroundf(slider.value)
}
```

I have this code, but what does `slider:UISlider` mean?

Comment: That the parameter has to be an object of UISlider class https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158

Comment: This Question is being discussed in [How to handle questions about mandatory language knowledge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411809/how-to-handle-questions-about-mandatory-language-knowledge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you need to have at least one UISlider connected to your IBAction. You can connect more than one slider to the same action. When the user moves one of them you can access the sender's slider properties just as slider.anyproperty.